# Users don't see app in admin.google.com apps after installing from marketplace

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

So a new surprise from GSuite Marketplace. For some of our users the next thing happens:
- install the app in the marketplace
- go to admin.google.com >> apps >> marketplace apps

The app is not there. The worst part is that we can't even reinstall, because when the user goes to the app page in the marketplace, he sees "Please uninstall app for domain in Admin Console.", but as mentioned above we don't see it in the console :facepalm:

So somewhere it *is* installed, but we can't see it in the admin console.

Please advise what could b causing this, and how we might attempt to remedy this issue.

Comment: Is the admin of the domain installing this App for all the users? or is each user who have to install it?

Comment: @jds1993 admin is installing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look in to the reports (Admin.google.com > Reports >audit Logs > token ) to check if in fact it was actually installed and to which users it was.

If still you cant find it, in the reports neither. You can contact Google Support so they can tell you why is not there.